# An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to this and I'm here to seek some help from the experts

This project is using ASP.NET Core & C#.

I am trying to initialize my database.. However, I keep facing these issues and I am not sure how to debug it.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtT6V.png

This project required 3 databases. An Expense Database, a Category Database and a Sub-Category Database. Below shows how are they going to connect with each other.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoU8F.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHxqf.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZTnb.png

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of code or error messages. They are text. Post them as text, formatted appropriately. We should be able to read your code easily AND copy and paste it to run it for ourselves. We can't copy code from a picture. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't provide `expenses`, So I don't know what's in that, I just can give you some advice about this error message .The error occurs in your `Category` table, The way a FK works is it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table. It seems that You are trying to insert a record with a value in the foreign key column that doesn't exist in the foreign table.

For example: If you have Books and Authors tables where Books has a foreign key constraint on the Authors table and you try to insert a book record for which there is no author record.

So i suggest you check if any of the situations I mentioned above are found in your code.

Comment: Hi @unknownStar, If my answer help you solve your question, can you mark it as answer? Thanks you very much.

Comment: sure^^ sorry I'm new to StackOverflow too✌